# View PDF file on local server using google API

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-document-viewer

How to view PDF file or any other extensions like [doc - xls] on local server using Google Doc API

I used a Wordpress plugin called "Embed Any Document" and works, but the files should be accessible on the web.

but in my case the file is locally, so how to make it with the Google API directly if its not possible with any plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The [Google drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/) gives you access to insert update delete and download the files on Google drive.

There is no API that will allow you to view the file.  You will need to download the file then view it.